# How to download all attachments from email threads using EWS API 2.0 in C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have setup and downloaded attachments from EWS successfully and here is the brief code i am working on:

```
 EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.HasAttachments));

                           foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                           {
                               if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                               {
                                   string sFilePath;
                                   FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
```

I came across the problem where it is only downloading the attachment from the latest email thread not from the previous threads. Look at below email scenario I sent a email with attachment1 to my friend, he replied with Attachment2 to me.. how can i retrieve both the attachments from the email and relate to the email threads they belong to.

Email Scenario:

> This is Second thread with new attachment
>
> ## Attachment 2
>
> On Tue, Sep 1, 2015 at 9:53 PM, stash it
>   > wrote:
>
> Checking Document Attachment
>
> ## Attachment 1

Comment: Thats because the attachment only exists in that one email.  You would need to track back through the email conversation history too for both sent and received messages.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample code or any useful link please

Comment: I dont have anything to hand at the moment, but that is the reason why youre not able to download the attachments from previous messages. You would need to iterate though each of the messages, i would go by subject \ conversation for each folder in the mailbox to do this, but it would potentially be slow because of the amount of messages that you would potentially be going through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out:

```
ConversationId convId = item.ConversationId; 

PropertySet properties = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly,                                                       
                                                ItemSchema.Subject,
                                                ItemSchema.InReplyTo,
                                                ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
                                                ItemSchema.DateTimeSent,
                                                ItemSchema.DisplayCc,
                                                ItemSchema.IsFromMe,                                                         
                                                ItemSchema.DisplayTo,
                                                ItemSchema.HasAttachments,
                                                ItemSchema.Attachments,
                                                ItemSchema.UniqueBody);

// Request conversation items. This results in a call to the service.         
ConversationResponse response = service.GetConversationItems
(convId,properties,null,null,
ConversationSortOrder.TreeOrderDescending);

foreach (ConversationNode node in response.ConversationNodes)
{
    foreach (Item item in node.Items)                   
         {
        Console.WriteLine("   Received: " + item.DateTimeReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("   Received: " + item.uniquebody);
        Console.WriteLine("   Received: " + item.subject);
         if (item.HasAttachments)
                 {
              foreach(Attachment attach in item.Attachments)
                           {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attach as FileAttachment;
                fileAttachment.Load(sFilePath);
                }
          }
      }
}
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx